# Best practice for filtering an array in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component called Tours that shows a full list of tours.
I have a link to a site called favorites which should display the tours with the favorite parameter set to true, and apart from that identical to the Tour component.

Is there a best practice for achieving this?
I can think of a few ways

1. Create a separate route to this component and filter based on the value in the route
2. Create a custom pipe that's triggered based on the route path

However, neither of them seem optimal to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I exclusively use the `filter` function, especially in cases such as yours. If you have an array of tours with a `favorite` property on each iteration, you could do this:

```
this.tours.filter((item) => {
            return (item.favorite === true)
        })
```

Or if you wanted a `filter` function with a `favorite` parameter, you could do this:

```
filterFavorites(favorite : boolean): Array<string>{
        return tours.filter((item) => {
            return (favorite)? item : null;
        })
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Edit: you could definitely create a pipe, but I think that would be overkill in your case, unless you intend to use the pipe multiple times in other places.

Comment: That makes sense. I receive my dataset as an observable and set it to a local value using subscribe (i.e. result.subscribe(res => this.locations = result)

If I try to filter this data in NgOnInit I get an empty array as the data is not yet loaded. Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: You could try filtering within the subscribe function, sometimes that catches the data. 
`result.subscribe(res => this.locations = result; this.favorites = this.locations.filter ... (etc))`

Comment: This technically works. However, I get the field I want to subscribe on from a different field in my code. When I use your suggested approach I can filter on all values except for location.like. However, when I write a simple map function and console.log location.like it is set correctly

This is my full script:
this.locations = af.database.list('/trips')
   .map((locations) => {
     return locations.map((location) => {
       location.like = af.database.object(`/likes/${this.uid}/${location.$key}`);
       return location;
     })
  });

Comment: I'll create a separate thread for that question and marks this one as answered. Thanks again

Comment: Cheers, good luck! Put 'Angular 2 Observable' somewhere in the title of the new question